# which mariadb version supports bit_count function which returns value greater than 64 bit

Tags: mariadb

I want to know mariadb version which support BIT_count Function:
which gives me result for below query:

```
 SELECT
 BIT_COUNT(BINARY '101100111100100100110101101110110011011001100111110010010110010011011011000100111000000111011011011100101111110110001100100010010111000000100011100001111001101100011001101010110100001011101001001101111000001110011001100000111100111011001110010001100101110100011000101101110001100110111000101000110111000001011001111010101101010000010101001000101001100000111001011011110111100001110100001110101010010010000010010001011101000111011000000010111000100110011101000110011011110101001110100000100001011111001001011000111010000110000111111010010111110100000010100001110010011011000010' ^ BINARY '101100111100100100110101101110110011011001100111110010010110010011011011000100111000000111011011011100101111110110001100100010010111000000100011100001111001101100011001101010110100001011101001001101111000001110011001100000111100111011001110010001100101110100011000101101110001100110111000101000110111000001011001111010101101010000010101001000101001100000111001011011110111100001110100001110101010010010000010010001011101000111011000000010111000100110011101000110011011110101001110100000100001011111001001011000111010000110000111111010010111110100000010100001110010011011011111');
```

this query works well in mysql8.0.1
which gives me output as 4

But I we have mariadb5.5.52  installed on our server
I don't have any knowledge of mariadb ,so I want to know on which version this query supported.

Comment: Good question, but based on [this chart](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/) there appears to not be any guaranteed compatability between MySQL 8.0.1 and any version of MariaDB.

Comment: Oracle and MariaDB are each marching forward, occasionally syncing selected features.  _Today_, 8.0.1+ is your only choice for that bleading-edge feature.

Comment: (It is possible to move the CheckMark to a different answer, thereby letting rmuller delete his answer.  See his comment.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works in version 10.0.

If you are using 10.1 you might get some warnings, see [this article](http://www.geoffmontee.com/bitwise-operators-with-binary-fields-in-mysql-and-mariadb/) for details.

**UPDATE**

This answer is only correct when using a BIGINT value. See Rick James comment.

Comment: As I read that article, MariaDB does no yet support `BIT_COUNT` for anything bigger than 64 bits.

Comment: My bad, i use the bit_count function with a BIGINT and that works .... Cannot delete this answer however, because it is accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and MariaDB are *mostly* compatible.  The differ in dozens of obscure ways -- ways that almost no one every uses.  You are asking about one such way.

Oracle extended MySQL 8.0.1 to include "Bit" functions beyond 64 bits (`BIGINT`); they now work on `BLOB`.  MariaDB has not (yet) included that code.  They may or may not ever include it.  (I suspect they will consider it in 10.3.)